# Iterate through months using T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I don't know if this operation is possible in T-SQL, but I want to iterate through each month and use the month number as part of the name of a row. When a try to use my variable of the month number I can't concatenate the name of the row. Here is an example of my code. Thanks a lot in advance for any help.

```
WHILE @mes < 12 BEGIN
SET @mes = @mes + 1
SET @xmes = iif(@mes>9,'0'+convert(varchar, @mes),convert(varchar, @mes))


    DECLARE #Meta CURSOR LOCAL FOR
        SELECT ven, meta FROM vendmeta
    OPEN #Meta
    FETCH NEXT FROM #Meta INTO @ven, @meta

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN   
        --here is where I need to use my variable but not work 
        update #Reporte set m+@xmes = @meta where ven = @ven

    FETCH NEXT FROM #Meta INTO @ven, @meta
    END 
    CLOSE #Meta
    DEALLOCATE #Meta

END
```

Comment: Please be more specific when you say that it doesn't work. Do you mean that you get an error message? If so, what is the error message? Also, table structures, example data, and expected output would be very helpful. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: you can't do "m+@xmes" without some dynamicSQL. But this cursor and while loop is most likely not necessary. If you could supply what data actually is in "SELECT ven, meta FROM vendmeta" and the output format you are trying to achieve in #reporte i'm sure you will get good sugestions.

Comment: It would be good if you could provide us with the table structure and some sample data. I am just guessing here but I think you would NOT need a nested loop to solve this issue. But it's hard to say without knowing what structure your data has.

Comment: Does "part of the name of a row" mean _column_? What is a _row name_?

Comment: Another approach would be to update all 12 columns using `case` or `iif`, e.g. `update #Reporte set m01 = iif( @mes = 1, @meta, m01 ), m02 = iif( @mes = 2, @meta, m02 ), ... where ven = @ven`. Depending on the number of rows affected and index on `ven` the performance might be acceptable. Tip: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you initializing @mes = 0?  To do this, you might have to build the update statement as a text string and then execute it.

```
Set @sql = 'update #Reporte set m' + @xmes + ' = ''' + @meta + ''' where ven = ''' + @ven + ''''
Exec(@sql)
```

Comment: No problem, if it is the answer to your question, please mark it so. @KamranFarzami the answer was to concatenate the M and the `@xmes` variable to determine the column name. Once those are concatenated in a string, it is executing the statement and pulling the the `@meta` and `@ven` variables on execution. Let me know if that doesn't make sense

Comment: @WyattShipman it makes sense thanks. I think I misunderstood the question

Comment: how would this work if the `@sql` has no idea what the variables `@meta` and `@ven` are? i think you should treat those parameters the same way you're treating `@xmes`

Comment: @JamieD77 it would read the variables on execution. It should work to write it like you are talking about as well. The way I wrote it should keep you from having to concatenate apostrophes for the text variables.

Comment: to use variables in your dynamic sql,  you need to use sp_executesql and pass the parameter values in

Comment: @JamieD77 thanks for the fact checking. I updated my answer to concatenate the variables into the string.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the month names ? Here you have 2 posible solutions in order to get the month names:

1.-

```
    ; WITH cte AS (
    SELECT CAST( '19000101' AS DATE ) AS dtColumn
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD( M , 1 , dtColumn ) 
    FROM cte 
    WHERE DATEADD( M , 1 , dtColumn ) < '19010101' 
)

SELECT dtColumn, UPPER( DATENAME( M, dtColumn ) ) AS monthName 
 FROM cte
```

2.-

```
; WITH cteLVL1 AS( 
    SELECT 1 AS colName UNION ALL SELECT 1 
)
, cteLVL2 AS(
    SELECT 1 AS colName FROM cteLVL1 AS a CROSS JOIN cteLVL1 AS b
)
, cteLVL3 AS(
    SELECT 1 AS colName FROM cteLVL2 AS a CROSS JOIN cteLVL2 AS b
)
, cte AS(
    SELECT 1 AS colName , ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY colName ) AS rn , CAST( '19991201' AS DATE ) AS dtColumn FROM cteLVL3 AS a
)

SELECT TOP 12 colName
, rn
, dtColumn
, DATEADD( M , rn , dtColumn ) AS dtColumnCalculated
, DATENAME( M , DATEADD( M , rn , dtColumn ) ) AS monthNameCol
FROM cte
```

Regards!